# Unable to change read write permissions to hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to copy text file into hdfs location.
I'm facing Access issue, so I tried changing permissions.
But I'm unable to change the same facing below error:

```
chaithu@localhost:~$ hadoop fs -put test.txt /user
put: Permission denied: user=chaithu, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

chaithu@localhost:~$ hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user
chmod: changing permissions of '/user': Permission denied. user=chaithu is not the owner of inode=user

chaithu@localhost:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 2 items
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs supergroup          0 2017-12-20 00:23 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2017-12-20 10:24 /user
```

Kindly help me how can I change the rights to full read and write for all users to access the HDFS folder.

Comment: @Chaitu Remove the bigdata and yarn tags from the question.

Answer (score 7):

First off, you shouldn't be writing into the /user folder directly  nor set 777 on it

You're going to need a user directory for your current user to even run a mapreduce job, so you need to `sudo su - hdfs` first to become an HDFS superuser.

Then run these to create HDFS directories for your user account

```
 hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/chaithu
 hdfs dfs -chown -R chaithu /user/chaithu
 hdfs dfs -chmod -R 770 /user/chaithu
```

Then `exit` from the hdfs user, and `chaithu` can now write to its own HDFS directory.

```
hadoop fs -put test.txt
```

That alone will put the file in the current user's folder.

---

Or, if that's too much work for you write to /tmp instead

---

A lazy option is to rewrite your user account to the super user.

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs 
hadoop fs -put test.txt /user
```

And this is why hadoop is not secure or enforce user account access  by default (i.e. never do this in production)

---

And finally, you can always just turn permissions completely off in hdfs-site.xml (again, only useful in development phases)

```
 <property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you observe your `hdfs dfs -ls` result you see that only HDFS super user have the permissions to that path.

**you have two solutions here**

One is to change the permissions to chaitu through root user and making chaitu as user or owner, something like this `hdfs dfs -chown -R hdfs:chaitu /path` then you will be able to get access to that being a owner. Other dirty way is to give `hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /path` from the root, from the security stand point this 777 is not good.

Second one is using ACLS which gives you the temporary access

Please go through this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html) for more understanding.

More on [ACLS](https://hortonworks.com/blog/hdfs-acls-fine-grained-permissions-hdfs-files-hadoop/)

This is so basic and important for you to learn, try the above suggested ones and let me know if those don’t work I can help more based on the error you get.